# Where does Visual Studio save pre/post build scripts?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration, msbuild, projects-and-solutions, solution

The pre-build and post-build events can be added from the properties window of a visual studio project inside the IDE. But where are these scripts stored ? I need to check-in these scripts to our tfs server. So, **what is/are the files that should be checked-in** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MsBuild doesn't create any files for the pre/post build events (afaik; and if it did, they would have a randomly generated filename and end up in the systsm's temp directory anyway): what you enter in de dialogs in VS is passed directly as a string to the [Exec command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx)'s `Command` parameter. Furthermore that string is also just stored as-is in your project file, which is likely checked in already.

So if you enter a plain command (like `echo hello`) as a build event, you don't have to do anything special. If you enter the path to a batch file or exe however, you better place that file in a directory that is also under source control and use a relative pathm, and you have to make sure that file is also checked in.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually figured it out that the build-scripts are all actually saved inside the .csproj file itself.